# JPA passing list to IN clause in native query

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I have this query:

```
   @Query(
      value = "select distinct ID_RIGHT from TDK_SEC_HOTEL_RIGHT osrr where osrr.ID_RIGHT in ?1", 
      nativeQuery = true)
        List<String> findAllByHOTELs(List<String> HOTELs);
```

but i have this error when running it:

```
  Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setObjectCritical(OraclePreparedStatement.java:8547)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setObjectInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:8029)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setObjectInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:8804)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setObject(OraclePreparedStatement.java:8779)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.setObject(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:217)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.StatementFacade$StatementProxy.invoke(StatementFacade.java:118)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy143.setObject(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabasePlatform.setParameterValueInDatabaseCall(DatabasePlatform.java:2648)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseCall.prepareStatement(DatabaseCall.java:836)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:628)
... 100 more
11:01:36.510 [https-openssl-apr-1062-exec-1] ERROR
com.hostels.web.filter.HostelsResponseFilter - Request
processing failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Exception
[EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services -
2.7.5.v20191016-ea124dd158):
org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type
Error Code: 17004
Call: select distinct ID_RIGHT from TDK_SEC_HOTEL_RIGHT osrr where
osrr.ID_RIGHT in ?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can you try this query:

```java
@Query(
      value = "select distinct ID_RIGHT from TDK_SEC_HOTEL_RIGHT osrr where osrr.ID_RIGHT in :hotels", 
      nativeQuery = true)
List<String> findAllByHOTELs(@Param("hotels") List<String> HOTELs);
```

In the query above, :hotels is a named parameter that you bind to the HOTELs list.

Comment: Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Missing IN or OUT parameter at
index:: 1\

Comment: HOTELs list you're passing to the findAllByHOTELs method can be empty?  An empty list passed for an IN clause can cause issues.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to share a bit more information to debug what's going wrong.
I recreated a small example that seems to work: https://github.com/Lefeverw/stackoverflow-passing-list-jpa

Based on the error `Invalid column type` I suspect there's something wrong with the variable type of `ID_RIGHT`. Given the code you provided this column should have type `VARCHAR` (as that maps to String).